# azure sql database index cardinality zero

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database

azure sql server query is slow: 198 seconds.

my table store about 1 000 000 rows (lat, lng, price, title, id).

I do that to best perf:

```
ALTER DATABASE db1 SET AUTO_CREATE_STATISTICS ON;

ALTER DATABASE db1 SET AUTO_UPDATE_STATISTICS_ASYNC ON;

CREATE INDEX t1_lat_index ON t1(lat);

CREATE INDEX t1_lng_index ON t1(lng);

CREATE INDEX t1_price_index ON t1(price);

UPDATE STATISTICS t1;
```

but the query is still slow:

```
select top 100 * from t1 where lat > 46 and lat < 47 and lng > 3 and lng < 5 order by price;
```

may because indexes (lat, lng, price) cardinality still zero ?

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
select top 100 *
from t1
where lat > 46 and lat < 47 and lng > 3 and lng < 5
order by price;
```

is problematic, because the comparisons are inequalities.  You might start with the compound index: `t1(price, lat, lng)`.  This covers the `where` and `order by` clauses, so they might be faster.

Otherwise, you might want to look into [spatial indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934196.aspx) for this type of query.  I think Azure supports them.

Comment: CREATE INDEX t1_llp_index ON t1(lat, lng, price);

    CREATE INDEX t1_pll_index ON t1(price, lat, lng);

still slow